# active and passive window background color

Tags: c#, window

Need help with changing a passive window's color. So the window will have two different colors, one when it's activated and one when it's deactivated(passive).

These are the two methods I need to call:

```
 void Activated(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }


    void Deactivated(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackColor = Color.Blue;
}

private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the methods. I just need to know how to call them? I have tried with an if-statement, but i can't get it to work.

Comment: Call them, if you really need them, from the events Fung showed you. These are being raised automatically.